# Return True when set 1 contains ANY value from set 2

Tags: apex, trigger, set

I have the below trigger

```
trigger OpptypeLogTrig on Opportunity (before insert) {

    Set<Id> Accountids = new Set<Id>();
    Set<id> Oppsid = new Set<Id>();

    for(Opportunity Opplist1 : Trigger.new){
        Accountids.add(opplist1.accountid);
        oppsid.add(Opplist1.id);

    }

    Set<String> ProductFamiliesAssests = [Select Asset_family__C from Asset where accountid in :Accountids];
    Set<String> ProductFamiliesOpps = [Select id from OpportunityLineItem where opportunityid in :oppsid];

    for(Opportunity Opplist1 : Trigger.new){
        IF(
        opplist1.createddate < opplist1.account.first_order_date__C + 180
        ){
            Opportunity_type__c = 'New Business';
        }
        Else if (ProductFamiliesOpps CONTAINS any value FROM ProductFamiliesAssests){

            Opportunity_type__c = 'Upsell';

            }
        Else{

            Opportunity_type__c = 'Cross-Sell';
        }
}
```

The piece i am having issue with is

```
 Else if (ProductFamiliesOpps CONTAINS any value FROM ProductFamiliesAssests){

        Opportunity_type__c = 'Upsell';

        }
```

I have had a look at the ContainsAll method but this looks like it will only return true if Set 2 contains all the values in set 1

I need it to return true if the same values appears in both sets even if another value in set 1 is not in set 2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's kind of awkward, but I've always just used a third set:

```
Set<String> firstSet = new Set<String>(), 
  secondSet = new Set<String>(), 
  thirdSet = new Set<String>();
// populate first and second set
// then...
thirdSet.addAll(firstSet);
thirdSet.retainAll(secondSet);
// And yet later...
// There was at least one overlapping value
if(!thirdSet.isEmpty()) {
```